# How do I scroll a window in Firefox that does not have scrollbars?

Tags: firefox, scroll

We have some pages that we are developing that are pop ups.  We disable the scroll bars in general for these pop ups. However, during development there is some debugging info that shows up past the view port which we cannot get to because the page does not have scroll bars.

In IE we can click and drag and that will scroll the window but for Firefox that does not seem to be the case.

Is there an easy way to scroll in a Firefox window that does not have a scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of ideas:

- If you click on the page and use the up and down arrows, does that work?  I find that helpful for mis-behaving websites whose scrollbar doesn't go down far enough.
- If not, perhaps you could enable the scrollbars by passing in and verifying a DEBUG variable... That would allow you to keep off the scrollars in production, but give you the advantage of having them during development.